# Making use of ASP.NET Core's JSON to Model conversion outside of Controllers?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization

I need to convert Json strings to Model representations, but outside of Http request pipeline in an ASP.NET Core application.

Passing data into, our out of this pipeline lets me seamlessly convert between json and model - or dynamic - representations. But now that I manually need to transform a model to a json representation and then back to a model I find myself working manually with a Newtonsoft JObject. which is messy because I can't be sure I have implemented it correctly / the way ASP.NET Core has. And ultimately will be the wrong serializer when we upgrade to 3.0

So, surely there is a way to invoke / request the ASP.NET Core serialiser so I can get the same behaviour?

I am thinking of creating a fake controller and invoking actions on it - this seems rather convoluted and possibly would expose unwanted functionality to callers.

Comment: Can't you just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json)`?

Comment: JsonConvert is the Newtonsoft library. I want - if it exists - the ASP.NET Core factory function that gives me the correct converter to use - where "correct" is the same serializer that is/would be used by ASP.NET Core in its http request pipeline.

Comment: In 2.x there is no abstraction so you will need to use JSON.Net directly. For 3.0 I believe there is an abstraction you can use.

Comment: Given that JSON is a standard, I can't see the problem here. Either you have a valid JSON string or not, no matter which tool you use. That is the whole point with a standard, to work cross solutions. Also, as mentioned, from Core 3.0 Microsoft will provide their own built-in serializer, but it will still generate standard JSON.

Comment: Simply put, there is no _wrong serializer_, there is either those that provide valid JSON and those that doesn't (haven't seen any yet that doesn't though). Where they differs is their features, where some is fast, some have clever methods/configurations and some in between.

Comment: Except there is. Any serialiser that adds unnecessary dependencies to my project, and or introduces potential version conflicts because ASP.NET Core and I now for some reason, expect different versions of Newtonsoft is a wrong serialiser.

Comment: Well, internally ASP.NET Core 2.x's built-in "JsonMediaTypeFormatter" use JSON.Net/Newtonsoft. From Core 3.0 you can choose to either keep that, or use Microsofts own serializer, either way they will still provide the same JSON result. And so will different versions of Newtonsoft, they just come with different features, performance, security etc.

Comment: These 2 articles might be useful: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-formatters ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2